# How to avoid the duplicates in drop-down list by using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using linq to write the query, whenever I am creating  a new entry in a form,gender drop down list is generating duplicates in that list.if i create 2 new entries 2 options like this.
[male
female
male
male
].
my project is visual studio-angularJS-web api-linq-sql-entity framework.

Comment: You will probably need to show us your code that's doing this in order to get an answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `Distinct()` LINQ method.

Comment: i cant show my code coz this project has some restrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
var filteredList = originalList
  .GroupBy(x => x.Gender)
  .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: this one is really fine to select the distinct values, but is there anyway to restrict the new values in gender table?

Comment: do you mean in a database table? You could add a unique constraint to avoid duplicates being entered.

Comment: do u want me to add a new check constrain?

Answer (score 0):

Linq has a Distinct() method, which will use the default equality methods to ensure only one copy of each item is returned.

```
var items = new List<string>{'bob', 'frank', 'bob', 'jim'};
var distinctItems = items.Distinct();
//items should have 3 items, bob frank and jim
```

However if you're dealing with objects the default equality methods will be reference - meaning you'll get one copy of each object, but two objects with identical fields won't be considered equal.  To fix that you need to overload Equals and GetHashCode.

Also, the order items will come out of Distinct is not guaranteed.

Comment: I have a special table for genders in sql, and i am taking that as entity . so is there any way?

Comment: Thank you, but i am just doing in this way by putting this as in comment, and its working

Comment: public int? GenderID { get; set; }
       // public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

Comment: does it effect the remaining pages, if i dont use vrtuals

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Virtual - distinct will determine if two things are the same (and thus one needs to be excluded) by calling GetHashCode.  To understand why, read about Equals() and GetHashCode() methods off of Object.  

If you want your object to respond properly to Distinct(), you will need to override GetHashCode and Equals in the object.  Otherwise it will just make sure you don't have more than one REFERENCE to the same object in your list.